# Understanding pointer cast

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, pool

I am reading this interesting article. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/746630/O-Object-Pool-in-Cplusplus

I can't understand this line `_firstDeleted = *((T **)_firstDeleted);`

`_firstDeleted` already has type `T*`. Can anyone explain the purpose of that statement?

Comment: Wtf? Invoking UB via strict aliasing is what this does. (I believe.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen, hard to say without seeing the full code, but very likely indeed.

Comment: It is an implementation of a singly linked list. The code is storing a pointer to the next item at the beginning of the memory referred to by `_firstDeleted`.

Comment: The summary at the top says `To delete an object, it is pretty simple. We invoke the destructor and then we will consider the object as a pointer. Such pointer will be set to point to the actual "first free" object then its address will be put as the first deleted item;` Whether or not that actually makes sense, I don't know.

Comment: `struct _Node` Omg. Don't waste your time with this garbage.

Comment: Also *extremely* dubious: Article presents no results at all. Just some handwaving *"C++ doesn't do this, but it's awesome, trust me"*. Like *"this doesn't happen in C++."* What is *"C++"* in the first place? Every compiler can allocate memory any way it likes.

Comment: Alright, he claims one can get results with some sample code in his .zip, admitting that it is a contrived scenario. That's something I guess, I overlooked that claim at first glance. Still, the code itself is an atrocity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an object is destroyed, its first `sizeof(T*)` bytes are overwritten with the address of the next free object.
(That is, `*T` is actually no longer storing a `T` but a `T*`, if you see what I mean. The cast performs this reinterpretation. It is formally rather undefined.)

This has the effect of the deleted objects forming a linked list of available memory blocks.

Reusing the object memory for this list means that you don't need a separate list of free blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Code like `*((T **)content) = _firstDeleted;` is known as "deferencing a type-punned pointer", aka breaking the strict aliasing rules, aka undefined behavior.  What the author is trying to do is have `_firstDeleted` point to the first "free" object in the map of uninitialized memory, with all the undefined behavior goodness that comes with it.

Modern C++ (even though the article was published in 2014) would probably use safer facilities for uninitialized storage, like [the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory).